# API SOAP V2 CatalogProductList WSDL changes in catalogProductEntity dont take effects

Tags: api, soap, wsdl, vb.net

I need to add fields to Magento complexType `name="catalogProductEntity"`, I change all the needed files: `Api.php`, `wsdl.xml`, `wsi.xml` but no changes were made in the SOAP answer.

**`Api.php`:**

```
        foreach ($collection as $product) {
        $result[] = array(
            'product_id' => $product->getId(),
            'sku'        => $product->getSku(),
            'name'       => $product->getName(),
            'set'        => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
            'type'       => $product->getTypeId(),
            'category_ids' => $product->getCategoryIds(),
            'website_ids'  => $product->getWebsiteIds(),
            'manufacturer' => $product->getAttributeText('manufacturer')
        );
    }
```

**`wsdl.xml`:**

```
            <complexType name="catalogProductEntity">
            <all>
                <element name="product_id" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="sku" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="set" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="type" type="xsd:string"/>
                <element name="category_ids" type="typens:ArrayOfString"/>
                <element name="website_ids" type="typens:ArrayOfString"/>
                <element name="manufacturer" type="xsd:string" />
            </all>
        </complexType>
```

**`wsi.xml`:**

```
            <xsd:complexType name="catalogProductEntity">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="product_id" type="xsd:string" />
                <xsd:element name="sku" type="xsd:string" />
                <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                <xsd:element name="set" type="xsd:string" />
                <xsd:element name="type" type="xsd:string" />
                <xsd:element name="category_ids" type="typens:ArrayOfString" />
                <xsd:element name="website_ids" type="typens:ArrayOfString" />
                <xsd:element name="manufacturer" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
```

But the ouput in my VB variable inspector is:

```
category_ids    {Length=3}  String
category_idsField   {Length=3}  String
name    "MPZ121293" String
nameField   "MPZ121293" String
product_id  "140238"    String
product_idField "140238"    String
set "9" String
setField    "9" String
sku "MPZ121293" String
skuField    "MPZ121293" String
type    "simple"    String
typeField   "simple"    String
website_ids {Length=8}  String
website_idsField    {Length=8}  String
```

As you see I can't see manufacturer field.

I'm sure that the error is in the `wsdl.xml` because if I change the `api.php` I can't see manufacturer in the field name.

**`Api.php`:** (see manufacturer assigned to name)

```
        foreach ($collection as $product) {
        $result[] = array(
            'product_id' => $product->getId(),
            'sku'        => $product->getSku(),
            'name'       => $product->getAttributeText('manufacturer'),
            'set'        => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
            'type'       => $product->getTypeId(),
            'category_ids' => $product->getCategoryIds(),
            'website_ids'  => $product->getWebsiteIds(),
            'manufacturer' => $product->getAttributeText('manufacturer')
        );
    }
```

And the VB global inspector gives:

```
category_ids    {Length=3}  String
category_idsField   {Length=3}  String
name    "My company"    String
nameField   "My company"    String
product_id  "140238"    String
product_idField "140238"    String
set "9" String
setField    "9" String
sku "MPZ121293" String
skuField    "MPZ121293" String
type    "simple"    String
typeField   "simple"    String
website_ids {Length=8}  String
website_idsField    {Length=8}  String
```

I put SOAP cache off in `php.ini`, delete temp files in Magento, PHP, Apache server, Windows/tmp and `C:/temp`, reboot server, clear Magento caches... but nothing...

Any idea? Any help?

---

Yes in **http://ROOT/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1** I can see:

```
<complexType name="catalogProductEntity">
<all>
  <element name="product_id" type="xsd:string"/>
  <element name="sku" type="xsd:string"/>
  <element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
  <element name="set" type="xsd:string"/>
  <element name="type" type="xsd:string"/>
  <element name="category_ids" type="typens:ArrayOfString"/>
  <element name="website_ids" type="typens:ArrayOfString"/>
  <element name="manufacturer" type="xsd:string"/>
</all>
```

My VB simple code:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Dim pws As New MagentoService.MagentoService
    Dim sesionID = pws.login("xxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    Dim result

    Dim filters As New MagentoService.filters
    Dim complexFilter(0) As MagentoService.complexFilter
    complexFilter(0) = New MagentoService.complexFilter
    complexFilter(0).key = "sku"
    Dim assEnt As New MagentoService.associativeEntity
    With assEnt
        .key = "sku"
        .value = "M2233121293"
    End With
    complexFilter(0).value = assEnt
    filters.complex_filter = complexFilter
    result = pws.catalogProductList(sesionID, filters, "0")

End Sub
```

I forgot to put this... Could be a problem with VB?. Thanks.

Comment: if you take a look at `http://ROOT/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1` do you see your changes in the WSDL generated?

Comment: Yes in http://ROOT/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1 I can see: <complexType name="catalogProductEntity">
<all>
  <element name="product_id" type="xsd:string"/>
  <element name="sku" type="xsd:string"/>
  <element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
  <element name="set" type="xsd:string"/>
  <element name="type" type="xsd:string"/>
  <element name="category_ids" type="typens:ArrayOfString"/>
  <element name="website_ids" type="typens:ArrayOfString"/>
  <element name="manufacturer" type="xsd:string"/>
</all>
I forgot to show this... Could be a problem with VB?. Thanks.

Comment: then the problem is not the wsdl. it's something else.

Comment: any idea, where can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error.

MagentoService is a **Web Reference in Visual Studio** 2013, and **don't update wsdl definition automaticaly**. I must update the Web Reference manually in Visual Studio 2013.

So easy... so dificult...

Thanks Marius you guide me to the solution!